# When does $\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x}{2} = x\log x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried using the quadratic formula and I also attempted to solve it for $x$ but just ended up with $8x = 8x$. I can see on a graph that they do meet at a two points, but I can't figure out where they meet.

Comment: Is this $\frac12(x^2-x)$ or $\frac1{2(x^2-x)}$?

Comment: It is the first you mentioned, x^2/2 - x/2. I edited the title for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious solution is $x=1$, when both sides of
$$\frac12(x^2-x)=x\log_b x$$
become $0$. Note that the right side of
is defined only when $x>0$ so we shall assume so.
Thus we are allowed to divide by $x$ and arrive at
$$\frac12(x-1)=\log_b x$$
and after exponentiation
$$\tag1x=\sqrt{b^{x-1}}.$$
While we don't find an explicit expression for the solution, $(1)$ can be used as a recursion formula for a sequence quickly converging to a solution. The  value depends on which logarithm we use and can be obtained only as a numerical approximation this way as $x\approx 0.749228$ if $b=10$ and  $x\approx 3.5128624$ if $b=e$.

**EDIT:** For some bases $b$, the inverse of $(1)$ is better suited to iterate towards the fixpoint, i.e. to let $x_{n+1}=1+2\log_bx_n$.
For example, this way one obtains $x\approx 6.319722$ if $b=2$.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! I did type lg for base 2 but I think it got corrected

Comment: Sometimes its useful define $0\log0$ as $0$, because of its limit for $x\to0$ (for example in the Information Theory). That would give us solution $x=0$.

Comment: What do you use as the initial number in the recursive formula? I can't seem to find a proper solution for base 2

Comment: @DannyBirch I added the solution for $b=2$, which needs a different iteration for convergence. By the way, I am used to $\lg=\log_{10}$, $\ln=\log_e$, $\operatorname{ld}=\log_2$ (and $\log$ is either any or $\ln$).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah yes, it seems that is the ISO standard. Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $x\neq0$:
$$x-1 = 2\log x$$
And so $x=1$ is a solution (by inspection). I'm afraid the second solution can't be obtained without using the [Lambert W function](http://www.linkedin.com/jobs?viewJob=&jobId=4153838&trk=jobs_jig_jobs&goback=%2Egmp_2526482), but numerically it's around $~3.5$.

Comment: Great, I'll have a look at that thanks :D